# Two contradictory ways to calculate $(e^{2\pi i})^i$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

As we know:

$$e^{i2π} = 1$$

so here's the first way that we can calculate the expression in the title:

$$(e^{i2π})^i = 1^i = 1$$

however, if before we simplify $e^{i2π}$ to $1$ we multiply the powers which we're allowed to do, we get a different result:
$$(e^{i2π})^i = e^{ii2π} = e^{-2π} ≈ 0.18 $$

What's the explanation to this?

Comment: I feel like power-to-a-power doesn't hold in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: $z^i$ is multivalued.

Comment: [Complex exponentiation doesn't obey the same rules as real exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities)

Comment: What's the contradiction? $(e^{i2\pi})^i$ can be equal to both of those.  Why do you think that is a contradiction?

Comment: you should make sure that you understand the definition of $e^{ix}$ as it is not really $e$ to the power of $ix$... this "notation" comes from the Taylor series associated with $e^x$ and with $sin(x)$ and with $cos(x)$

Comment: "however, if before we simplify e^(i*2π) to 1 we multiply the powers which we're allowed to do" Allowed to do? According to PEMDAS, we do parenthesis first. In general, it does not hold for non-positive $a,b,c$ that$$(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$$You don't even need to use complex numbers to see that this is false. For example,$$1=((-1)^2)^{1/2}\ne(-1)^{2/2}=-1$$

Comment: You can find here **many, many** other questions where the answer is the same: $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ fails for complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex number exponentiation doesn't follow the rules for rational exponentiation. It is true that:
$$(\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}, a> 0):(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$$

However, things change for $\mathbb{C}$:
$$a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}, (a^b)^c\:\text{might not equal } a^{bc}$$

#### But why?

$\log(w^z) = z\log(w)$ doesn't hold for all $w,z\in\mathbb{C}$, regardless of how we treat $\log$. Very relevant information regarding this topic can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities). That being said, going with your first method is the correct choice in this case.

Comment: You probably mean $$\forall a\in\mathbb R,\ a>0$$ since otherwise the statement has trivial counterexamples.

Comment: Again incorrect: one must assume $a>0$, not only $a\ne0$.

Comment: @Did Sorry. Now it's fixed. Was in a rush when I edited and didn't take the time to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that$$(\forall a,b\in\mathbb{C}):(e^a)^b=e^{ab}.\tag{1}$$However, what is the meaning of $(e^a)^b$? Since $a$ is an arbitrary complex number, $e^a$ is an arbitrary non-zero complex number. So, what is $z^w$ when $z,w\in\mathbb C$ and $z\neq0$? It is *any* number of the form $e^{w\log z}$, where $\log z$ is *some* logarithm of $z$. So, the equality $(1)$ must be used with a lot of precautions.